# The "Xamarin.Build.Download.XamarinBuildAndroidAarProguardConfigs" task could not be loaded from the assembly

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, proguard

So I enabled proguard on one of my application. I had some problems with it but I solved them all ( had to update proguard, make a symlink of android sdk without spaces )

Now I enabled pro guard on another application and i'm constantly getting this error:

```
The "Xamarin.Build.Download.XamarinBuildAndroidAarProguardConfigs" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\xxx oud\packages\Xamarin.Build.Download.0.4.6\build\Xamarin.Build.Download.dll.  Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.
```

Anybody knows a way to solve this? Not sure what more I could add

Comment: Please include a full diagnostic build error log.

Comment: The issue is resolved after restarting my computer, thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I resolved my issue by restarting my computer

**Edit**: It seems restarting visual studio might be enough to resolve the problem

Comment: In my case I just had to restart VS

Comment: For mme it still persisted after that. U cleaned u project after restatt perhaps?

Comment: It happened again just now, restarting VS was enough, anyway if I had not read ur post I would have searched the web for hours...

Comment: + close and let visual studio to start the emulator too.

Comment: Restarting VS for Mac didn't work, rebooting the computer didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Restarting Visual Studio or my computer didn't work for me. The correct fix is to modify the package version of `Xamarin.Build.Download` to something that works.

For me, it meant changing the packages that referred to version `0.4.7` to `0.4.3`.

It seems that a lot of people have had trouble with 0.4.7.